# How to delete specific data from a particular column in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app has a sqlite table which has the following columns:

- CONTACT_ID = "_id",
- CONTACT_NAME = "con_name",
- CONTACT_USERID = "con_userid",
- CONTACT_ACCID = "con_accid".

The content of the column `con_accid` is of type `String`. The primary key of the table is `id`. I want to delete data of particular `con_accid`. For example, I want to delete item names of all items which have `con_accid` as `"raja"`.  I have tried the following different queries but both are not working:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(ContactsDB.TABLE_CONTACTS, allColumns,
            ContactsDB.CONTACT_ACCID + "= ' " + comment +"'"  , null, null, null, null); 
    if (cursor != null) {
       cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "delete");
            ContactsInfo _comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            long id = _comment.getId();
            database.delete(ContactsDB.TABLE_CONTACTS, ContactsDB.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id  , null);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE con_accid='" + comment;
Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Do you want to delete the **entire** row data(all the columns) where `con_accid = raja` or you want to delete **only** the name from `con_name` where `con_accid = raja`?

Comment: i want to delete entire row where `con_accid = raja` those all available row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should delete all rows in your database where `con_accid = raja`:

```
database.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, CONTACT_ACCID + " = ?", new String[] {"raja"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "database" instance is created with .getWritableDatabase(). And your query should work without any issue.